# Get the username from a login php script

Tags: php, function, class, authentication

I'm using a login script that I have found in [Innvo.com](http://innvo.com/1299199492-simple-login-script/#comment-5489), they do not answer... I have modified a little bit this code though, I need to retrieve the username value at the login page and I can not find the way... first I will put the code of the file (login.php) with all the classes that take care of the login, then the code that should go in the login page (access.php), where I need to retrieve the username of the logged user... thanks

## FILE: login.php

```
// Some pre-defined constants to indicate the login state
define('LOGIN_NOERROR',0);
define('LOGIN_USER_CREDENTIALS',-1);
define('LOGIN_USER_EXISTS',-2);
define('LOGIN_USER_NONEXISTS',-3);
define('LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKSENT',-4);
define('LOGIN_PASSWORD_BADMATCH',-5);
define('LOGIN_PASSWORD_TOOSHORT',-6);
define('LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKEXPIRED',-7);
define('LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED',-8);
define('LOGIN_AWAITS_APPROVAL',-9);


class auth {
    private $db = null; // Database object
    private $baseurl = 'https://exemple.com/recover.php'; // a URL that will have this script included. Used for password reset emails which require a hyperlink

    private $hashfunction = 'sha256'; // Hash function used, this is always computed by PHP due to mysql versions giving binary & non-binary outputs depending on its version
    private $hashlength = 32; // Length of $this->hashfunction output in binary format
    private $secret = 'LDGH$$$$$'; // A secret salt used in passwords alongside user-specific salts, change this

    public $account = array(); // User details on successful login

    private $errors = array( // Error array for when there is a UI issue for the user
        LOGIN_NOERROR=>'',
        LOGIN_USER_CREDENTIALS=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Usuari i/o contrasenya incorrectes!</h3>',
        LOGIN_USER_EXISTS=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Aquest usuari ja existeix al sistema!</h3>',
        LOGIN_USER_NONEXISTS=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Aquest usuari no existeix al sistema!</h3>',
        LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKSENT=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Li hem enviat un correu electrònic amb un enllaç per a restablir la contrasenya. Ha de seguir les instruccions que s\'esmenten al correu per a crear una contrasenya nova.</h3>',
        LOGIN_PASSWORD_BADMATCH=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Les contrasenyes no coincideixen!</h3>',
        LOGIN_PASSWORD_TOOSHORT=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Les contrasenyes han de tenir al menys 8 caràcters!</h3>',
        LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKEXPIRED=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">L\'enllaç per a restablir la contrasenya ha caducat!</h3>',
        LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">La seva sessió ha caducat!</h3>',
        LOGIN_AWAITS_APPROVAL=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">El seu compte espera l\'aprovació de l\'administrador del lloc, rebrà un correu quan això estigui fet!</h3>'
    );
    public $forms = array( // Unique HTMLforms used
        'signin'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'username'=>array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Correu electrònic','icon'=>'envelope'),
                'password'=>array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Contrasenya','icon'=>'lock')
            ),
            'submit'=>'Accedir',
            'message'=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Introdueixi el seu correu electrònic i la seva contrasenya per accedir-hi</h3>'
        ),
        'signup'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'newusername'=>array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Correu electrònic','icon'=>'envelope'),
                'newnamelastname'=>array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Nom i cognom','icon'=>'envelope'),
                'newpassword'=>array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Contrasenya','icon'=>'lock'),
                'confirmnewpassword'=>array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Confirmi la contrasenya','icon'=>'lock')
            ),
            'submit'=>'Crear un compte nou',
            'message'=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Si us plau, empleni tots els camps per a crear el seu compte.
                                                                És important que el correu sigui vàlid per a poder recuperar la contrasenya si fos el cas!</h3>'
        ),
        'lost'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'lostusername'=>array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Correu electrònic','icon'=>'envelope')
            ),
            'submit'=>'Envia\'m el correu',
            'message'=>'<br /><h3 style="margin-left: 20px;">Introdueixi el seu correu electrònic per a rebre les instruccions de recuperació de la seva contrasenya</h3>'
        ),
        'reset'=>array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'newpassword1'=>array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Contrasenya','icon'=>'lock'),
                'newpassword2'=>array('type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Confirmi la contrasenya','icon'=>'lock')
            ),
            'submit'=>'Restableix la contrasenya',
            'message'=>'Estableixi una nova contrasenya pell seu usuari!'
        )
    );

    // Initiate the database if its not connected already
    public function __construct($dbobj = null) {

        !$dbobj->connect_errno
            or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $dbobj->connect_errno . ") " . $dbobj->connect_error);
        $this->db = &$dbobj;

        if(isset($_COOKIE['cddzck']) && $this->session_validate()) {

            // Logged In here

            if(isset($_GET['logout']))
                $this->logout();
        }
        else {
            // Sign in attempt
            if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']))
                $this->login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
            // Sign up attempt
            else if(isset($_POST['newusername'],$_POST['newnamelastname'],$_POST['newpassword'],$_POST['confirmnewpassword']))
                $this->user_add($_POST['newusername'],$_POST['newnamelastname'],$_POST['newpassword'],$_POST['confirmnewpassword']);
            // Lost password, email submitted via form
            else if(isset($_POST['lostusername']))
                $this->password_reset_form($_POST['lostusername']);
            // Lost password area
            else if(isset($_GET['reset']) && $this->session_valid($_GET['reset'])) {
                // Form not submitted
                if(!isset($_POST['newpassword1'],$_POST['newpassword2']))
                    $this->session_check($_GET['reset'],'lostpassword');
                // Form submitted
                else
                    $this->password_reset($_GET['reset'],$_POST['newpassword1'],$_POST['newpassword2']);
            }
            // Login as user, for use within an admin area to impersonate a logged in user
            // You should add in the session value yourself in the admin area using $this->session_add($userid,$type = 'login') and then login via this method/URI
            else if(isset($_GET['cddzck']) && $this->session_valid($_GET['cddzck'])) {
                if(($this->session_check($_GET['cddzck'],'login') == 0) && isset($this->account['id'])) {
                    setcookie("cddzck",$_GET['cddzck'],time() + 21600);
                    $this->redirect();
                }
                else 
                    sleep(1);
            }

            // None shall pass (unless logged in...)
            die($this->form(LOGIN_NOERROR,(isset($_GET['form']) && in_array($_GET['form'],array('signup','lost','reset')) ? $_GET['form'] : 'signin')));
        }
    }

    // Add a session to the hash table
    public function session_add($userid,$type = 'login') {
        $hash = hash($this->hashfunction,bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($this->hashlength)));
        $result = $this->query('INSERT IGNORE sessions (hash,sessiontype,userid,created)
            VALUES (UNHEX(\''.$hash.'\'),\''.$type.'\','.$userid.',UNIX_TIMESTAMP())');
        return $hash;
    }

    // Run this in a cron job once an hour to remove stale sessions and lost password requests
    public function housekeeping() {
        // Remove sessions older than 6 hours
        // Remove password reset authentication strings after 1 hour
        $this->query('DELETE FROM sessions
            WHERE (sessiontype = \'login\' AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 21600)
            OR (sessiontype = \'lostpassword\' AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3600);');
    }

    // User is not logged in, display one of the forms
    private function form($error,$formname) {

        // Throttle failed attempts
        if($formname == 'signin' && $error != 0)
            sleep(1);

        // Show a sign up or sign in link in the navigation
        if($formname == 'signin')
            $link = '<p><a href="?form=signup">Crear compte nou</a></p>';
        else
            $link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">Accedir</a></p>';

        // Get all form fields and buttons
        $formfields = '';
          foreach($this->forms[$formname]['fields'] as $name => $field)
              $formfields .= sprintf('<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-%s blue"></i></span>
                    <input name="%s" type="%s" placeholder="%s" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    ',$field['icon'],$name,$field['type'],$field['placeholder']);
        $formfields .= sprintf('<p class="center col-md-5"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">%s</button></p><p>&nbsp;</p>',$this->forms[$formname]['submit']);

        // Navigation links for sign up/sign in/forgot password
        $navigation = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li>'.$link.'</li>
    <li><p><a href="?form=lost">Recuperar contrasenya</a></p></li>
</ul>';

        // Form wrapped in bootstrap 3.0 HTML with variables inserted
        $form = sprintf('<div class="well col-md-5 center login-box">
            <div class="alert alert-info">%s </div>
            <form method="post" action="?form=%s" class="form-horizontal">%s</form>
</div>',($error != 0 ? $this->errors[$error] : $this->forms[$formname]['message']),$formname.(isset($_GET['reset']) ? '&amp;reset='.$_GET['reset'] : ''),$formfields);

        // The above HTML is taken from a bootstrap template, you can place it into an existing template as such, using %s placeholders for the content area and navigation, for example.
        // echo sprintf(file_get_contents('template.html'),$navigation,$form);
        // otherwise, here is the raw output that is used

        echo $navigation.'<hr>'.$form;

        exit(0);
    }

    // User is trying to log in
    private function login($username,$password) {
        $result = $this->query('SELECT id,active,salt,password
            FROM users
            WHERE active = \'1\' AND username = \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($username).'\';');
        // We fetch the row because MySQL's SHA2() functions returns either a binary of hex string format depending on version.
        // For simplicity the comparison is made in PHP, though it's trivial to change this to save the roundtrip of data

        if(!($this->account = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
            die($this->form(LOGIN_USER_CREDENTIALS,'signin'));
        else if($this->account['password'] != pack('H*',hash($this->hashfunction,$this->secret.$this->account['salt'].$password)))
            die($this->form(LOGIN_USER_CREDENTIALS,'signin'));

        // Successful login, you're about to be logged in and redirected
        $this->query('UPDATE users
            SET lastlogin = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
            WHERE id = '.$this->account['id']);
        $hash = $this->session_add($this->account['id'],'login');
        setcookie("cddzck",$hash,time() + 21600);
        $this->redirect();
    }

    // Add a new user to the database and send the mail to awaits approval
    private function user_add($username,$namelastname,$password,$password2) {
        if($password != $password2) // Passwords do not match
            die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_BADMATCH,'signup'));
        elseif(strlen($password) < 8) // Password less than 8 characters
            die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_TOOSHORT,'signup'));

        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($this->hashlength);
        $hash = pack("H*",hash($this->hashfunction,$this->secret.$salt.$password));

        $this->query('INSERT IGNORE users (created,username,namelastname,salt,password)
            VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),\''.$this->db->real_escape_string($username).'\',\''.$this->db->real_escape_string($namelastname).'\',\''.$this->db->real_escape_string($salt).'\',\''.$this->db->real_escape_string($hash).'\');');
        if($this->db->affected_rows < 1)
            die($this->form(LOGIN_USER_EXISTS,'signup'));
 //ach       $this->login($username,$password);
         $emailcontents = sprintf("Nou usuari $username ($namelastname) esperant l'aprovació pel seu compte!");
         $from = "CddZ-IAC";
         $headers = "From: $from";
         mail('andres@chandia.net','Nou usuari al CddZ esperant l\'aprovació!', $emailcontents, $headers, '-f ' . $from);
         die($this->form(LOGIN_AWAITS_APPROVAL,'signin'));
    }

    // Reset a password, displays the reset password form if a valid authentication string is provided
    private function password_reset_form($username) {
        $result = $this->query('SELECT id
            FROM users
            WHERE username = \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($username).'\'');
        if(!($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
            die($this->form(LOGIN_USER_NONEXISTS,'lost'));

        $hash = $this->session_add($row['id'],'lostpassword');
        $emailcontents = sprintf("Benvolgut $namelastname, ha de seguir aquest enllaç per a restablir la seva contrasenya:\n\n%s?form=reset&reset=%s\n\nSalutacions!",$this->baseurl,$hash);
        // Here you would send the reset link to an email address (the whole idea of ensuring this is the rightful owner of the account
        // ... but for testing purposes , the output of the email is below
        mail($username,'Restableixi la seva contrasenya', $emailcontents);
        //echo "<hr>$emailcontents<hr>";

        die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKSENT,'reset'));
    }

    // On successful reset password link, allow the user to reset their password
    private function password_reset($reset,$password,$password2) {

        if(($error = $this->session_check($reset,'lostpassword')) < 0)
            die($this->form($error,'reset'));
        if($password != $password2)
            die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_BADMATCH,'reset'));
        elseif(strlen($password) < 8)
            die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_TOOSHORT,'reset'));

        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($this->hashlength);
        $hash = pack('H*',hash($this->hashfunction,$this->secret.$salt.$password));

        $this->query('UPDATE sessions AS s
            INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.userid = u.id
            SET u.salt = \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($salt).'\',u.password = \''.$this->db->real_escape_string($hash).'\'
            WHERE s.hash = UNHEX(\''.$reset.'\') AND s.sessiontype = \'lostpassword\'');
        $this->query('DELETE FROM sessions
            WHERE hash = UNHEX(\''.$reset.'\') AND sessiontype = \'lostpassword\'');

        $this->login($this->account['username'],$password);
    }

    // Log out
    private function logout() {
        $this->query('DELETE FROM sessions
            WHERE sessions.sessiontype = \'login\' AND sessions.hash = UNHEX(\''.$_COOKIE['cddzck'].'\');');
        setcookie("cddzck","",time() - 3600);
        $this->redirect();
    }

    private function redirect() {
        header('Location: //'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->clean_uri());
        exit(0);
    }

    // Removes login-specific details from the current URI
    private function clean_uri() {
        return preg_replace("'[?&](form|reset|logout|cddzck)=[^&]+'",'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }

    // Validate that a user-provided session is syntactically valid
    private function session_valid($hash) {
        return preg_match("'^[a-f0-9]{".($this->hashlength*2)."}$'",$hash);
    }

    // Check a session cookie to see whether it's valid, and logged in or not
    private function session_validate() {
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['cddzck']) || !$this->session_valid($_COOKIE['cddzck']))
            die($this->form(LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED,'signin'));
        if($this->session_check($_COOKIE['cddzck'],'login') < 0) {
            setcookie("cddzck","",time() - 1800);
            die($this->form(LOGIN_SESSION_EXPIRED,'signin'));
        }
        return $this->account['id'];
    }

    // Look up the hash table for a given session in a given context
    private function session_check($hash,$type = 'login') {
        $result = $this->query('SELECT u.id,u.flags,u.created,u.lastlogin,u.username
            FROM sessions AS s
            INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.userid = u.id
            WHERE s.hash = UNHEX(\''.$hash.'\') AND s.sessiontype = \''.$type.'\';');
        if(!$this->account = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            unset($_GET['reset']);
            die($this->form(LOGIN_PASSWORD_LINKEXPIRED,'reset'));
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // MySQL queries
    private function query($sql) {
        $result = $this->db->query($sql) or die(__LINE__.' '.$this->db->error.' '.$sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

## FILE: access.php

```
<?php
// Call me admin.php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','dbusr','dbpasswd','dbname'); // Change these details to your own
include_once('login.php');
$_auth = new auth($db); // Anything past here is logged in
printf('<span style="float: right; margin-right: 29px;">[<a href="?logout=1"> Sortir </a>]</span>');
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend _not_ to use this class, as it uses an outdated password hashing. Or modify it to use php's password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try, and what about the question I did?

Comment: What does `$_auth->account` contain?

Comment: I tried to retrieve that, but I couldn't neither...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your Auth-Class in login php with that method:

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return isset($this->account['id']) ? $this->account['username'] : "No user found.";
}
```

After you login you can access that username :

```
<?php
// Call me admin.php
$db = new mysqli('localhost','dbusr','dbpasswd','dbname'); // Change these details to your own
include_once('login.php');
$_auth = new auth($db); // Anything past here is logged in
//Username:
$username = $_auth->getUsername();

printf('<span style="float: right; margin-right: 29px;">[<a href="?logout=1"> Sortir </a>]</span>');
?>
```